# Why is the linear map surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am going through the proof of theorem 3.60 in Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, 3rd ed., which states the following:

> Suppose $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is a basis of $V$ and $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ is a basis of $W$/ Then, $\mathcal{M}$ is an isomorphism between $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ and $\mathbf{F}^{m,n}$

Proof:

It is easy to show that $\mathcal{M}(S + T) = \mathcal{M}(S) + \mathcal{M}(T)$, and $\mathcal{M}(\lambda S) = \lambda\mathcal{M}( S)$, for $S,T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and $\lambda \in \mathbf{F}$. It follows that $\mathcal{M}$ is linear.

It remains to show that $\mathcal{M}$ is injective and surjective. We begin by proving injectivity. Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$, and $\mathcal{M}(T) = 0$. It follows from the definition of a matrix that $Tv_k = 0\; \text{for}\; k = 1, \ldots, n$. Since $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is a basis of $V$, this implies that $T = 0$, and therefore $\mathcal{M}$ is injective.***

We now show that $\mathcal{M}$ is surjective. Suppose $A \in \mathbf{F}^{m,n}$ and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ such that

\begin{equation*}
Tv_k = \sum_{j = 1}^{m} A_{j,k} w_j,\; \text{for}\; k= 1, \ldots, n
\end{equation*}

It follows from the definition of a matrix that $\mathcal{M}(T) = A$, and therefore the $\operatorname{range} \mathcal{M} = \mathbf{F}^{m,n}$

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Question:

I am having trouble understanding the surjective part of this proof. Why does $A \in F^{m,n}$ and $Tv_k$ defined the way it is prove that the map is surjective? Can someone help explain this piece of the proof. Is it because they are letting $A$ be the $m \times n$ matrix with arbitrary entries?

Comment: Is $\mathcal{M}$ the map sending $T$ to the matrix of $T$ in the bases in question?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. They start with an arbitrary $A \in F^{m, n}$, and show that one can always construct some $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ such that $\mathcal{M}(T) = A$; this is the definition of surjectivity.

There are a few details worth mentioning.

1. To understand why $T$, as they have defined it, is a linear map, you need to recall that a linear map $T:V\to W$ is completely specified if you know what it does to a basis $v_1, \ldots v_n$ of $V$. (If you know $Tv_1, \ldots, Tv_n$, then $T(c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n) = c_1 Tv_1 + \cdots + c_n T v_n$.)
2. You need to verify that $\mathcal{M}(T)$ (with $T$ as they define) does indeed equal $A$. This follows easily from the definition of "matrix of $T$ with respect to bases $\{v_i\}$ and $\{w_j\}$."

Answer (score 0):

We need to check that $\mathcal{M}$ is surjective. To this end, fix an $m\times n$ matrix $A$. We need to produce $T$ such that $A=\mathcal{M} (T)$. Let $T$ be defined as in the body of your question. Now note that, if $B=\{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$.
$$
\text{col}_i (\mathcal{M}(T))=[Tv_i]_B=(A_{1i},\dots,A_{mi})^T=\text{col}_i(A)
$$
where $\text{col}_i(\cdot)$ is the $i$th column of the matrix in question. Since this holds for every $i$, $\mathcal{M}(T)=A$.